# How to display the UIImageJPEGRepresentation image in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I want to use UIImageJPEGRepresentation to add the image in iphone, in below code i am missing some thing I don't know how to add

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gameObj.gameThumbnails]];   
UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

imageView.image=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 90);// I am missing something here
[elementView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];  

 /*gameObj.gameThumbnails is an url like http://static.gamesradar.com/images/mb/GamesRadar/us/Games/X/X-Men%20Arcade/Bulk%20Viewer/360%20PS3/2010-10-11/192.168.30.167-image36_bmp_jpgcopy--game_thumbnail.jpg
*/
```

Please help me out of this

Answer (score 13):

u are setting comparison quality to 90. it should be between 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: Can you please explain with code how to display  .jpeg url image in iphone

Comment: NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gameObj.gameThumbnails]]; UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data]; imageView.image=myImage;

Comment: I have done same thing but image is of type .jpg. UIIMage support .jpg type. then how come it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

The UIImageJPEGRepresentation function returns an NSData (array of bytes) which represents a content of the image if compressed in JPEG.

To display it, you just need to use the UIImage directly.

```
imageView.image = myImage;
```

Comment: NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gameObj.gameThumbnails]];
 UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
 imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.9)];
 [elementView addSubview:imageView];
 [imageView release];

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you:

- Set your compression quality to 0.9(it MUST be between 0.0 - 1.0)
- Set the frame of the UIImageView correctly
- Don't make that UIImageView hidden

And if it still doesn't work then try the following:

```
[elementView bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
```

Hope it helps